# errors when using flatpicker calendar

Tags: javascript, html, calendar, datetimepicker, flatpickr

as i followed the official docs of flatpickr [in this link](https://flatpickr.js.org/getting-started/) for some reason the date picker didn't appear

here is what i did
i added this in my html head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>
```

and this in my js file

```
import flatpickr from "flatpickr";


flatpickr("#myflatpickr", {});
```

in the html body where i have the input:

```
 <input name="deadline" placeholder="Deadline" id="myflatpickr" required>
```

Comment: Try moving the `<script>` line to be the last thing before the closing `</body` tag, instead of in the `<head>`.

Comment: @PaulT still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move it after the element is present in the DOM indeed as Paul T said. Or add a on document ready function to it. Couldn't reproduce the error message you've got.. Maybe just leave out the import/require part?:

```html
<html>
  <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div><input name="deadline" placeholder="Deadline" id="myflatpickr" required></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        flatpickr("#myflatpickr", {});
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks it worked fine, but do u know how to make the calender appear on the first click ,sometimes i have to click twice in order for it to appear and sometimes only once , in your code snippet u have to click twice

Comment: I think it's because of the code snippet here in Stack Overflow. 
When I try it out in codepen.io for example, I only have to click ones.